# how to define/override Style for ContentView when it is child of ContentPage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have contentview as below

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
        <ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                     xmlns:convertors="clr-namespace:myApp.Convertors;assembly=myApp"   
                     x:Class="myApp.cwPart">

          <ContentView.Content>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                         BackgroundColor="White">
              <RelativeLayout Style="{StaticResource myStyle}"   
                              HorizontalOptions="Start"
                              VerticalOptions="Center">
```

I am referencing this `ContentView` inside multiple `ContentPage`s as example one below. Every `ContentPage` should set different `BackgroundColor`, `Height` and `Width`. That's why I thought that style should be defined in the `ContentPage` but it is throwing error that it is not recognized. How can I achieve this?

PS, interesting thing I am using Gorilla player to achieve such changes and Gorilla player doesn't return any error :)

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:convertors="clr-namespace:myApp.Convertors;assembly=myApp"
             xmlns:c="clr-namespace:myApp;assembly=myApp"
             x:Class="myApp.AppLogsPage"
             Title="{Binding AppName}" 
             x:Name="AppLogsPage">

  <ContentPage.Resources>

    <ResourceDictionary>

      <Style x:Key="myStyle" TargetType="RelativeLayout">
        <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="148"/>
        <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="80"/>
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White"/>
      </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>

  </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ContentPage.Content>
      <StackLayout x:Name="MainHolder">
        <c:cwPart   />
       ...
```

If I define ContentView Resources as below, it works fine but I am not able to override the Style defined inside ContentView

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
            <ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                         xmlns:convertors="clr-namespace:myApp.Convertors;assembly=myApp"   
                         x:Class="myApp.cwPart">

            <ContentView.Resources>

    <ResourceDictionary>

      <Style x:Key="myStyle" TargetType="RelativeLayout">
        <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="148"/>
        <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="80"/>
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White"/>
      </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>

  </ContentView.Resources>

              <ContentView.Content>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  BackgroundColor="White">
                  <RelativeLayout  Style="{StaticResource myStyle}"   
       HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" >
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues i would change in your approach but let's keep it simple. First of all i would use contentview with control template as;

in App.xaml;

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyControlTemplate">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  BackgroundColor="White">
                  <RelativeLayout HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" />
</StackLayout>
  </ControlTemplate>
```

then in your page.xaml

```
<ContentView ControlTemplate={StaticResource MyControlTemplate}/>
```

if you want to set individual styles for every page then you can create a control template for each of them.

Comment: I thought that I can use contentview like a Usercontrol in wpf. Thats why i prefer this approach but i am open for any other Suggestion if it works. If i understand correctly your advise is also a Static but not dynamic. I dont see any difference setting contentview height and weight in the app.xaml or in the view itself. Maybe I miss your Point?

Comment: Yes that's right, styles are static because they must be declared somewhere, there is no magic way to do it without defining them. But i understand your approach as i also have a WPF background. First of all be sure that your style is defined in App.xaml. Then try to set your style as you did before. Third, if you want to create a WPF like usercontrol then create a class deriving from ContentView with a constructor where you assign your styles, controltemplates from resource (app.xaml).

Comment: Ok i understand roughly but where do you define the Style for RelativeLayout. in ContentPage as in my question?

Comment: yup, define your global styles in app.xaml, and you can also define a style in specific page. And please take a look at my second answer regarding user control. Please be aware that if you have page on different project than your application PCL project in your solution, then you need to use DynamicResource keyword

Comment: Is it not putting extra load into memory if i have controltemplates defined in the app.xaml because it is loaded at application load and becomes like static in the memory.

Comment: Did use this approach in an enterprise consumer mobile app, no complaints about the memory so far :) Of course anything static is a cost but till you don't display a controltemplate on UI actually you only dump to memory the template code which you can imagine how small it is.

Answer (score 0):

To create a WPF like user control;

in App.xaml;

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyControlTemplate">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  BackgroundColor="White">
                  <RelativeLayout HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" />
</StackLayout>
  </ControlTemplate>
```

in the same project

```
public class CustomView: ContentView
{
   public CustomView()
   {
      ControlTemplate = (ControlTemplate)Application.Current.Resources.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "MyControlTemplate").Value;
   }
}
```

then you can use CustomView control/view in any xaml page. Don't forget to add xaml namespace of the CustomView in consuming xaml page.